# How to send audio to smartphone through bluetooth with Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, audio, bluetooth

I am working on a project that sends pre-recorded audio to communication devices in order to gauge intelligibility of the audio. I want to expand this to cover bluetooth accessories of the communication devices, but have hit a roadblock.

Is there a way in Python to simulate a bluetooth device that sends the pre-recorded audio to a connected smartphone as if it was spoken audio?

I have looked into multiple Python packages, namely PyBluez, but the most I have been able to do is connect a raspberry pi to my android phone temporarily. I haven't been able to send any data to the smartphone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No, there is no easy way to do that.